# Cesium - Control over slider window on click of polygon

Tags: slider, cesiumjs

Is there any way to not show this slider(as in screenshot below) on click of few polygons but to show on click of few other polygons?
To simplify what I mean to say, suppose This slider should be shown on click of blue polygon but should not be shown when red polygon is clicked, but I want to keep the ids for both polygons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's an undocumented property `[_enableInfoOrSelection][1]` (note - this is a private property and is unsafe for production - use with care).
The code is:

```
var handler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(viewer.scene.canvas);
var shouldShow = true;
handler.setInputAction(function(click) {
  viewer._enableInfoOrSelection = shouldShow;
  shouldShow = !shouldShow;
}, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_CLICK);
```

Note the line that controls weather to show or not to show the info box:

```
viewer._enableInfoOrSelection = shouldShow;
```

You'd might want to do something smarter (like to remove the info box in case a new entity was clicked etc., but it's up to you :)).

Here's a working code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Zb6fwNExkceAPpRyXnEw?p=preview